# Pdf to Pdf of Image with PdfBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm using pdfbox (1.8) to handle pdf on Windows (7 and above). I need to take an input pdf and convert to a pdf made by the same page but used as image (no text selectable etc etc). With small file i have no problem but when i have to convert bigger file i have no clue due to massive memory use.
I will post some code if it helps but the approach i'm using is simple: create a document by all the page saved as image taken from the source pdf.
I'm searching for some more memory and time efficent way to do this (i have to handle pdf with 1 or 2 k of pages).

Comment: Have you tried the -Xmx option of java?

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr yes, with rasonabler page number it solved my problem. But with 2000 pages the memory run really high.

Comment: You could try with the 2.0 version, but the bigger the PDF, the more memory it will need. Another strategy would be to encrypt the file with an empty user password and set restricted rights to prevent text copy & paste. (It is not real security, IT pros can still "liberate" such a document)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr we cannot rely on 2.0 since is not stable, or at least now we can't switch all software to 2.0. For password using it could be a trick, but the main focus is to convert in a stright way the pdf to pdfa (a pdf done only made of image) and plus other small things like make it not copyable. So we are tryng this approach

Comment: What exactly is so memory intensive? Is the resulting PDF so large or is the transformation process so bad? Maybe you should indeed post some code allowing us to reproduce the issue. Image resolution and sample original pages might be important information.